# Change datetime format in django or convert it to default

Tags: python, django, datetime

How do I convert custom datetime value ex. "15:22:03 13/11/2019"
to "13/11/2019 15:22:03" to add value as datetime in models?

Or how do i change default django datetime format? 
thank you

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) about `strptime` and `strftime`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this to change the default:

```
date = models.DateField(blank=False, default=datetime.now().strftime(("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")))
```

You can get the % strings at the bottom of this page to make it fit the format you asked for in the column, i can update it for you if you can't get it to work, i'm pretty good with Django.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: Thank you, but now im having issue   ["'15:22:03 13/11/2019' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."] when im uploading csv with my data.

Comment: Updated with place you can get the %s from so you can change the format, let me know if you still need help, i can probably get the format right for you if you have trouble

Answer (score 1):

```
You can convert your datetime string to datetime object and insert the date into your database.

from datetime import datetime

date_str = "15:22:03 13/11/2019"
temp_date = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y").date()
ModelClassName.objects.create(name='ABC', date_time=temp_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

installed   dateutil.parser
in view added

```
from dateutil.parser import parse as date_parse
```

and in csv import, in a needed row just added date_parse

```
reading_date=date_parse(READING_DATE),
```